# WPF: Access transformed Canvas coordinates in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, rendertransform

Is there a way in WPF to access the ScaleTransform Parameter of a Canvas Panel (which is created in the xaml File) in the Code Behind File?

**Use Case Example:**

I want to position a list of items inside a scaled Canvas like so:

```
<ItemsControl MouseMove="Control_MouseMove">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                              <TransformGroup>
                                   <ScaleTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform.ScaleX />
                                   </ScaleTransform>
                              </TransformGroup>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    </Canvas>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I also want to display the current position of my items inside the Canvas at Mouse over with a Pop-up. I am currently trying it this way:

```
public void Control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (!this.Popup.IsOpen)
        this.Popup.IsOpen = true;
    var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(this.SwLane);
    this.Popup.HorizontalOffset = mousePosition.X + 10;
    this.Popup.VerticalOffset = mousePosition.Y - 20;
    this.PopupContent.Text = System.Convert.ToString(mousePosition.X);
}
```

What I get is the canvas X coordinate inside the Popup (which makes sense to me). However, I would like to display the scale transformed "coordinates" of the canvas.

Is there a way to access the ScaleTransform Parameter in Code Behind so that I can visualise my transformed item position? Or should I do it in a different way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set an OnInitialized Handler where you build your transform in code-behind, save its constituent ScaleTransform as a private property and then assign it there as well after your window has initialized

Something crudely like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Background="White"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
        Initialized="MainWindow_OnInitialized"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItems" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="200" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private TransformGroup MyTransform { get; set; }
    private ScaleTransform SceneScale { get; set; }


    private void MainWindow_OnInitialized(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTransform = new TransformGroup();
        SceneScale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0, 0, 0);
        MyTransform.Children.Add(SceneScale);
        MyItems.RenderTransform = MyTransform;
    }
}
```

Now you could add a MouseLeftButtonDown Handler to scale things, for example:

```
    private void MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        SceneScale.ScaleX *= 1.1;
        SceneScale.ScaleY *= 1.1;
    }
```

For the coordinate thing, expose the current coordinates as properties.  Update them when the mouse moves.  Bind the UI to them

This might work better if you packaged it all in a control

Comment: I like this idea thanks! For the scale transform I need values from my DataContext. Can you also tell me how I would pass that to the Code behind?

Comment: You already have access to it.  The MainWindow class in my example is a FrameworkElement which means it has a DataContext property.   Whatever you are using in your app does as well

Comment: Now I got it. I was missing that I could use reflection to retrieve Properties from the Data Context. Thanks for your effort; I accepted it because having scale properties also helped.